# DllImport doesnt works on docker windows container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dllimport, windows-container

I have .net core console application which calls a cpp dll methods using DllImport. this cpp dll is compiled in windows and is not compatible with linux.
So we decided to dockerize this console application in a `Windows Container` docker image.
DllImport doesnt works there it say's

> 'Unable to load DLL 'Some.dll' or one it's dependencies ...'

We entered to the docker container using this command:

```
docker exec -it [ImageName] cmd 
app.exe --PrintCurrentWorkingDirectory
```

So we can see the Environment.CurrentDirectory on our application in container environment.
It was Ok, and our DLL file was placed in the same path that our application was there.

**Technical Information:**

- Base Image

  - Type: Windows Server Core
  - Call: `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`
- Our DLL dependencies found using (dependency walker):

> VCRUNTIME140.dll
> MSVCP140.dll
> KERNEL32.dll

- Our docker file:

> ```
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 as runtime
>
> SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
>
> ADD https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1 C:/setup/dotnet-install.ps1
>
> RUN C:/setup/dotnet-install.ps1 -Runtime aspnetcore -Channel 5.0 -Version latest -InstallDir c:\dotnet
>
> ENV DOTNET_ROOT=c:/dotnet
>
> ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe C:/setup/vc_redist.x64.exe
>
> RUN C:/setup/vc_redist.x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> copy . /app
>
> ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
> ```

**C# DllImport call:**

```
    [DllImport(@"Stitching.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern double get_version();
```

Here we tried to install `vs_redist.x64.exe`

What should we do to be able to load this DLL ?

Comment: Does it work outside the container, on dev machine with regular OS? How does code with `DllImport` look like?

Comment: Yes. it works on my local machine. I added my dllimport usage.